# CSS dynamic image width of parent div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a side project for fun and stumbled upon a problem.  I'm working on a dynamic width website, in which the content resizes based on the width of the browser.  I have a few images on the page that I want to resize based on the size of the browser, rather than on the size of the image.  Here's some code:

```
<div class="songblock">
 <div class="play" data-artist="Lorde" data-song="Royals" data-img="93158109.png">
  <div class="parrow"></div>
 </div>
 <img class="img lazyloadme" src="/img/pixel.png" data-original="http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/252/93158109.png" alt="PearlSquirrel"/>
 <div class="song">Royals</div>
 <div class="artist">
  <a href="/artist/Lorde">
   Lorde
  </a>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media only screen and (min-width:1px) and (max-width:1300px) {
.songblock{
    width:22%;
    margin-right:4%;
}
.songblock:nth-child(4n){
    margin-right:0px;
}
}
@media only screen and (min-width:1301px){
.songblock{
    width:17%;
    margin-right:3.75%;
}
.songblock:nth-child(5n){
    margin-right:0px;
}
}
.songblock{
height:auto;
float:left;
position:relative;
margin-bottom:30px;
}
.songblock:hover .play{
display:block;
}
.img{
height:auto;
width:100%;
min-height:125px;
min-width:125px;
float:left;
-webkit-border-radius:2px;
-moz-border-radius:2px;
border-radius:2px;
box-shadow: 0 4px 3px -3px #ABABAB;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 3px -3px #ABABAB;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 3px -3px #ABABAB;
}
```

Currently, the images being used are all 252x252px and the width that I am assigning to .img is a percentage.  What I want to happen is for the images to be a percentage of the parent div width and not a percentage of the size of the image itself.  I know that this can easily be done using javascript, but I am trying to make this app as lightweight as possible and would like to stick with css if it can be done.  Thanks for the help.  Please let me know if additional information would be helpful.

Edit: I solved the problem, thanks for all of the help!

Comment: When you set `img { width: 100% }` it is 100% of of the parent container. Resizing the parent container will "resize" the image, but you are still downloading the full size image from the server. http://jsfiddle.net/jammykam/hek35/

Comment: It seems to work ok for me. The issue is when you resize your browser, anything over 1300px the container div goes from 22% to 17%, you having 5 images per line (@1920px) and so your images suddenly shrink.

Comment: Exactly.  Everything works fine.  The only problem is that if last.fm supplies an image that is not exactly 252x252 pixels, then the height of the .img element is incorrect, if that makes sense.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. Couple of answers below about your selector class being incorrect. If you are going to do that, make sure your selector is `.songblock img` otherwise all images on your site will be affected. Or, add `<img class="img" ...>`. hth.

Comment: This belongs in the head of a responsive site. <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" /> Sorry about the delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the height and width attributes to my image before adding the css.  It seems to have temporarily alleviated my problem.  Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `data-original` in your image tag, and put that content in the `src` attribute.

When you change the percentage for `.img` it *is* taking the width of the parent, but the parent width in your example is only 22% of the window.

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/rehhz/3/) is a fiddle with all you've supplied.  [This](http://jsfiddle.net/rehhz/4/) is a fiddle with the proposed changes, as well as `.songblock` width changed to `width: 55%;` to show that the image scales correctly.

From this:

```
<img class="img lazyloadme" src="/img/pixel.png" data-original="http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/252/93158109.png" alt="PearlSquirrel" />
```

To this:

```
<img class="img lazyloadme" src="http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/252/93158109.png" alt="PearlSquirrel" />
```

Comment: The data-original attribute is used for lazy-loading the image.